# Is there a jquery widget for entering international phone numbers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, widget, phone-number

I need to accept international phone numbers on my HTML form.

Is there any open-source javascript / jquery widget for inputting international
phone numbers? I'm looking for something similar to what Skype has:

[image: skype-widget]

Desired features:

- Good usability. I realize this is vague; that's why I want to use something
  well tested, instead of writing my own.
- User can type in a number directly (+373 22 717171).
- User can select a country (Moldova), the widget automatically fills in the
  country code (+373), and lets the user type the rest of the number.
- Developer can programatically get / set the country code.

(This is NOT a question about validating phone numbers.
I already know how to do that using the javascript version of
[libphonenumber](http://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/).)

Comment: This is a question for Google, not StackOverflow.

Comment: @Blazemonger I googled before asking, but did not find anything suitable. In every example I found, people hacked together the behavior they wanted by hand.

Comment: Well, it's not a very common need. Are you unable to hack together your own solution?

Comment: That's what I ended up doing, but I still think that a reusable widget would be valuable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what you want, with some areas are removed, which can be found in the source code. 
https://github.com/Bluefieldscom/intl-tel-input

Answer (score 1):

I have created a simple widget in JS & HTML which accepts international phone numbers.

Easy to plug into your code

Works well on iphone, ipad and android phones

Very light weight

CSS sprites used in rendering the country flags – so there is no negetive impact on page load performance

You can change the UI as per your liking. 

Get the source code: [International telephone widget - github](https://github.com/deep7686/telephone-widget)

 Checkout the demo - [Demo](http://icslabs.in/demos/telephone-widget/)